# How to enter keystrokes like ENTER,TAB, etc. in firefox browser using protractor framework?

Tags: javascript, firefox, testing, protractor, ui-automation

I am trying to enter keystrokes(TAB) in my script.

I have used the following code:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
```

This is working in chrome but not working in firefox browser.

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN);
```

These 2 approaches are not even working in chrome also.

I need to run my script in firefox with entering keystrokes. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to init some element on the page and send the key chord to it.

```
element(by.id('<visible element on the page>')).sendKeys(Key.chord(protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.ENTER));
```

or try with browser actions:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.ENTER));
```